# Multiple collections in meteor common code

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I export common code (meteor methods) which involves multiple collections?

The 'normal' way I have seen from several tutorials is to place meteor methods along with the collection to be exported together, eg.:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';    
export const CollectionA = new Mongo.Collection('collectionA');
Meteor.methods({ methods involving CollectionA go here })
```

---

What if I have multiple collections? For example it might look something like:

CollectionA.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const collA = new Mongo.Collection('collA');
```

CollectionB.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const collB = new Mongo.Collection('collB');
```

PlaceForMeteorMethods.js:

```
import { collA } from './CollectionA';
import { collB } from './CollectionB';
Meteor.methods({ methods involving collA and collB go here })
//export?
```

After trying for some time, I resorted to placing the exact same Meteor.methods() code on both client and server. Is there a better way to do this?

Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. You could take a shortcut and just put your `PlaceForMeteorMethods.js` under `/lib` OR just make sure that file is imported by both your client code and server code, typically via code in `/imports/startup`

If you import a directory import will look for an `index.js` in that directory.

Comment: I didn't know we could import files like that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong. The example I was using had an `index.js` in the directory and import goes for that.